# Exit and re-enter after applying for a permesso di soggiorno while waiting with the receipt?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, italy

I'm in Italy on a study visa and I have a receipt for the permesso, I would like to leave for Africa for a short time before the permesso is issued. Will I be able to re-enter?  (I got a multiple-entry visa), but I won't have the permesso in time to leave with it. From some anecdotal reading [over here](http://www.meltingpot.org/Entry-and-exit-of-Italy-while-waiting-for-the-renewal-of.html#.VqJoI3UrKV4) seems it's possible, but I'd like a more authoritative answer, and I can't find one.
I only possess the receipts of the application.

Comment: Is your visa still valid?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is the authoritative answer i was looking for:

```
Foreigners awaiting renewal of their residence permits can leave 
and re-enter Italy if they hold:
1. the receipt issued by Italian Post offices (Poste Italiane S.p.A) certifying the submission of the application for renewal of their residence  permit or EC residence permit for long-term residents;
2. the expired residence permit;
3. their passport or other equivalent travel document .
```

source [is here](http://www.poliziadistato.it/articolo/10722/)

This applies to those waiting for the document for the first time:

```
The same facilitated procedure is granted to foreigners who have submitted their 
application for their first residence permits for employment, 
self-employment, or family reunification, provided that:
1. they leave and re-enter Italy through any Italian external border crossing point (cicular letter 11th March 2009);
2. they show their passport or other equivalent travel document, along with the entry visa specifying the reasons of their stay (employment, self-employment, or family reunification ) and the receipt issued by Italian Post offices (Poste Italiane S.p.A.);
3. they do not transit through other Schengen countries, as this is not allowed.
```

Comment: This answer seems to speak about _renewal_ of residence permits, whereas the OP sounds like he's awaiting having one issued _for the first time_.

Comment: sorry i failed to mention that scenario is also covered.

Comment: `provded that: ...` It's incomplete!

Comment: Hi, do you know if that applies for students waiting for the permit for the first time?

Comment: it applies, first time or subsequent times when  you renew.  never leave or reenter through schengen countries while only having the receipt/expired permesso, and  carry the expired one too+receipt on subsequent  applications on entry/exit.